# NSNetService says it is published, but it isn't visible on the network

Tags: cocoa, bonjour

I'm working on a little iOS app for my own use (initially, at least) and I thought I would use Bonjour to configure networking between two iOS devices.
My server's interface defines

```
NSNetService *netService;
```

and the implementation uses the following code to advertise its existence:

```
const NSString *kSEBonjourServiceDomain = @"";      //use defaults
const NSString *kSEBonjourServiceName = @"_test._tcp.";

//...

netService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:(NSString *)kSEBonjourServiceDomain type:(NSString *)kSEBonjourServiceName name:@"" port:sin.sin_port];
if (netService)
    {
    netService.delegate = self;
    netService.includesPeerToPeer = YES;
    [netService publish];
    }
else NSLog(@"Failed to create NSNetService");
```

When I start the server, my NSNetService object does call the -netServiceDidPublish: delegate method, but when I use Discovery to browse the bonjour services on my network, my service doesn't appear. Apart from the const strings, this code is the same as some code in one of my Mac apps (which works as expected) and also very similar to Apple's sample code.
I've gone through all the options in Xcode's capabilities tab in case I needed to add something there, but I can't see anything relevant. I've also read a bunch of documents and tutorials that don't mention having to do anything more than that, but it wouldn't surprise me to learn that this only works on iOS if you set an obscure build setting to a string that you had to learn about by reading the Human Interface Guidelines for watchOS last September.
So, can anyone enlighten me? What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried this with a name other than `@""`, that's safe to pass for the `domain`, but without a name, the DNS name would be `._test._tcp`, which might be interpreted in mDNS as `_test._tcp` and thus a search within that domain would result in nothing in the browser.

Comment: Well the docs say "`@""`—Registers the service in the default set of domains. Pass this value unless you have a specific reason not to", but I have also tried `@"local"`.

Comment: I'm not talking about the `domain`, I'm talking about the `name`.  The docs are clear on `domain`, but I think you're going to need a `name` to actually have the registration show up in the browser.

Comment: If you pass an empty string in as the name, it uses the device name. The docs are clear about that too, and I can see that it is working in my -netServiceDidPublish: method, which logs the name used. I was actually generating a longer name before, but cut it down to that in case there was some limit to the name beyond whats in the docs.

Comment: Yes, missed that in the docs due to the initializer overload. Have you tried using `dns-sd -B` to see what's being registered? Wondering if the problem isn't on the registration side, but on the discovery side.

Comment: I hadn't ever heard of dns-sd before, but unless I'm missing something, it seems to just be a less convenient way of doing what I've been using Discovery for ( https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/discovery-dns-sd-browser/id1381004916?mt=12 ). In any case, neither of them appears to see my service.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that due to a silly error elsewhere in my code, sin.sin_port was set to 0 by the time I was registering my NSNetService. Although NSNetService doesn't see this as a problem, it was causing the service to be ignored by service browsers.
So the answer is, a service with a port of 0 will register without error, but won't work.
Thanks to gaige for the assistance.